Not able to see azure 'LifecyclePolicyCompleted event' log
In Azure storage account I have added Rules under lifecycle management to move blob from one access Tier to another daily around 3AM to 4PM (Automatically) and it's working fine .
Small Code snippet of my rule is:
{
  "rules": [
    {
      "enabled": true,
      "name": "Moving blobs to cool Tier after 1 days",
      "type": "Lifecycle",
      "definition": {
        "filters": {
          "blobTypes": [
            "blockBlob"
          ],
          "prefixMatch": [
            "Data/output/"
          ]
        },
        "actions": {
          "baseBlob": {
            "tierToCool": {
              "daysAfterModificationGreaterThan": 1
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    ]
}

But I don't see any log or activity log regarding this.
I visited Lifecycle policy completed event. But I am not able to find such LifecyclePolicyCompleted event neither in logs nor in activity logs of storage account.
Am I missing any configuration, or where I can find this log.


In Azure storage account I have added Rules under lifecycle management to move blob from one access Tier to another daily around 3AM to 4PM (Automatically) and it's working fine .
But I don't see any log or activity log regarding this

In my environment, I created lifecycle management policy yesterday as same as like your rule.
Portal:

Still, I can't be able to see the LifecyclePolicyCompleted event log in my activity log even though the tier change to cold tier.
So, you can use the below KQL query to check the lifecycle management policy change to another tier.
Query:
StorageBlobLogs
|where UserAgentHeader contains "ObjectLifeCycleScanner" and OperationName contains "setblobtier"
|project AccountName,UserAgentHeader,OperationName,AccessTier,TimeGenerated,ServiceType,Uri
 

The above query retrieves logs from Azure Storage where the ObjectLifeCycleScanner changed a blob's access tier (setblobtier operation), showing details like account name, access tier, and operation time. It's used for monitoring lifecycle management activities in Azure Blob Storage.
Output:

You can also refer this MS-Document to subscribe to Azure Storage Blob Lifecycle Policy Events
